# ASP.NET MVC how to make an action that return a file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Hello 
I am generating an excel file inside my action that I would return to the user. How do I have to declare the action to return a file?

May I call this action with ajax?

thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Option 1: Use built in ActionResults, such as FilePathResult, FileStreamResult, FileContentResult

Option 2: Build a custom ActionResult to return your excel file (example: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=484&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)