# action that returns a file in MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

So, I don't get what I still should to to make a file downloadable within the action.

So, here is the controller that I have. Everything seems to work fine, except that I never receive any file to download client-side.

```
    <HttpPost()>
    Function meetingCP(idCont As Integer, idOpp As Integer, schedule As String) As FileResult
        Dim id As Integer = 0
        Dim iCSFile As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
        Dim startDate As Date = schedule
        Dim endDate As Date = startDate.AddMinutes(30)

        iCSFile.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR")
        iCSFile.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0")
        iCSFile.AppendLine("METHOD:REQUEST")

      [bla bla bla]

        iCSFile.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:Reminder")
        iCSFile.AppendLine("END:VALARM")
        iCSFile.AppendLine("END:VEVENT")
        iCSFile.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR")

        Dim StreamWriter As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\MvcApplication4\MvcApplication4\Content\test.ics")
        StreamWriter.WriteLine(iCSFile)
        StreamWriter.Close()


        Return File(iCSFile.ToString, "text/plain", "MeetingRequest.ics")
        'Return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(iCSFile.ToString()), "text/plain", "MeetingRequest.ics")
    End Function
```

And this action is called by ajax. Might that be the problem?

```
function meetCP(idCont, idOpp) {
    var meetCPSelect = ("#meettime" + idCont);
    var dateTime = $(meetCPSelect).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("meetingCP")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { idCont: idCont, idOpp: idOpp, schedule: dateTime },
        success: function (result) { }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use AJAX  for file downloads from the main HTML response.

A way to do this would be to use an invisible IFrame, make the ajax call refresh the iframe and set the src of the IFrame to the file you would like to send.

Comment: So As I though, the asynchronous querry was the problem. I don't really like your option. I'd like something more direct for the user. The purpose of this file is to let the user earn time. That way, the user would have to wait smth like 1s, and then have to re-click... I need something more direct. I'll try it with a simple html post.

Comment: Yeah, to be fair I'd agree that it's the best option with a post, it can get a bit messy with the AJAX call :)

Comment: Ok, with a simple post, the file download does work fine. However,I now have issues with passing datas from the view to the controller :-(...

Comment: Can you not send them when you're doing the post request? Just put them onto the query string?

Comment: Now, I've found how to do it. I had already done this once like that, I just needed to find where I did it. My actual problem is the following :      Return File(...) does always return a .txt file. I've tryed to change the contentType property (text/plain) into ics, ical, vcal, vcalendar,... I don't really know already how to fix it

Comment: What type of file are you trying to return?

Comment: Change the content type to "text/calendar"

Comment: No problems, I googled .ics mime type because that's what content type refers to, it came up with this link which details all file types: http://www.filesuffix.com/extension/ics.html

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell but it looks like you are creating a file on the fly?? If you have the path to the file you can use something similar to this to download the file. This works for me:

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile(string path, string fileName) {
    FileContentResult result = null;
    var file = path + fileName;
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(file)) {
        result = new FileContentResult(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file), "application/pdf");
    }
    return result;
}
```

In your view you just need something like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Your Filename", "DownloadFile", "YourController", new { path = @item.FileLocation, fileName = @item.CurrentFileName }, new { target = "blank" })
```

Comment: Yes I create the file on the fly. If I understand well your code, the file could always be downloadable? If there was a problem with the edition of the file, the user would then download the previous file that was created on the server? If I'm right, this doesn't meet my requirements :-(

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Use built in ActionResults, such as FilePathResult, FileStreamResult, FileContentResult (http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/03/actionresult-types-in-mvc2.aspx)

Option 2: Build a custom ActionResult to return your excel file (example: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=484&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

[ASP.NET MVC how to make an action that return a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935225/asp-net-mvc-how-to-make-an-action-that-return-a-file)